# Kernels of completely positive maps

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

In the excellent book “$C^*$-algebras and their automorphism groups” by Pedersen there are results on the left ideals $L_\phi$ associated to states $\phi$ on a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and more results in the special case of a pure state. It seems likely that the some of the definitions generalise to the case of a completely positive map $\psi:A\to B$ between $C^*$-algebras (the previous case just being $B=\mathbb{C}$). For purposes of looking at noncommutative ‘submanifolds’ it would be useful to consider the kernel of such a general cp map. I was wondering if there were already known generalisations of the results in Pedersen to cp maps $\psi:A\to B$, and any guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

For example, what special properties would a cp map which is an extreme point of the set of cp maps have, similar to the definition of pure state? What would this tell us about the kernel of the cp map? I suspect that people studying Hilbert $C^*$-modules must have looked at questions like these.

Comment: This is a comment on the "For example" portion of your question: Probably(?) the first place these questions were addressed are in  Section 1.4 of Arveson's beautiful paper "Subalgebras of C*-algebras." He address 3 extremal problems of CP maps when $B=B(H).$ The third of which is a characterization of extreme points of all CP maps $\phi:A\rightarrow B(H)$ such that $\phi(1)=K$ for some fixed positive operator $K.$ I don't know anything about more general $B$  but Arveson's paper is probably a good place to start.